# How should we handle an error while getting initial state from store in getDataFromTree

Tags: reactjs, graphql, server-side-rendering, react-apollo, apollo-client

## What I am trying to do

Render a page server side with data from our graphql server with errors.

## Context

Our GraphQL server speaks to multiple APIs and returns a graphQL response which is handled by Apollo UI.

Certain GraphQL errors are not considered critical, and we want to still render a page with it. E.g.

```
data: {
   thing: {
       id: "1234"
       name: "Thing"
       nonCriticalData: null
   },
   error: {
       graphQLErrors: [
           path: ['thing', 'nonCriticalData']
       ]
   }
}
```

With the above response we get from Apollo, we want to still render a page with `thing`. Looking at the implementation of `getDataFromTree` [here](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/blob/fb7065912178c67e35c8c3a765ab69473af67d63/src/server.ts#L141-L148), *any* error will get thrown, without the rest of the data.

## How we plan to handle our errors

Here is a snippet of how we plan to handle our code:

```
getDataFromTree(app)
    .then(() => {})
    .catch(error => {

        const content = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(app);
        const { data } = client.getInitialState();

        console.log("data", data); <-------------- We need data here
        console.log("error", error); <———————— errors are here

        // render page with data
    });
```

Please let me know if there are ways around this, or whether I have missed 
something.

### Extra questions:

1. Should `getDataFromTree` even throw errors? It feels like the responsibility should lie with the consumer.